# Setting styles with JavaScript before rendering

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I have a list of images that are shown in a div each. The width of the divs will vary since they are specified as a percentage of their containers. The objective of that is to get a flexible design.

The images are wider than their containing divs, but all images do not have the same width. I would like to shift the images by setting a negative margin-left on the images, and in that way center the images in their containers.

Since the negative margins will depend on the width of the image, I need to check the width before setting the margins.

```
function marginsOfImages() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var parent = images[i].parentNode;
        var parentWidth = window.getComputedStyle(parent, null).getPropertyValue("width");
        /*In order to remove the "px" from the style: */
        var indexOfPx = parentWidth.search("px");
        parentWidth = parseInt(parentWidth.substring(0, indexOfPx));
        var imageWidth = window.getComputedStyle(images[i], null).getPropertyValue("width");
        indexOfPx = imageWidth.search("px");
        imageWidth = parseInt(imageWidth.substring(0, indexOfPx));
        var value = parentWidth + 90; //Want to shift the image 90px to the left
        if (imageWidth > value) {
            images[i].style.marginLeft = (value * (-1)).toString() + "px";
        }
    }
}
window.onload = marginsOfImages;
```

The problem is that the images are rendered without any margin at first, and then after a second or so they will get a margin depending on their width when the JavaScript has finished; the appearance of the images will change after the page apparently has already loaded.

How can I set the correct margins before showing anything of the images? I need to load all images before determining their dimensions, right?

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use a javascript library like jquery?

Comment: I could have used jquery, might have got some neater code that way. I'm just new to it so thought it was easier with javascript in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with @Prescott in that adding a class that displays the images is probably the way to go. A more generic approach, however, is to add a "js-loaded"-class to the `html` element and then you can always use that. I also always use a "js" or "no-js"-class to style differently as well:

```
<script>
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

    html.className = html.className.replace('no-js', 'js');

    window.onload = function () {
        html.className += ' js-loaded';
    };
</script>
```

And then you could simply:

```
<style>
    html.js #images img {visibility: hidden}
    html.js-loaded #images img {visibility: visible}
</style>
```

Comment: the idea of a generic js-load is one I haven't thought before (because I don't do this often), but I'll have to incorporate that into my future work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used powerbuoy's idea of applying the 'js-loaded' class and then making the images visible. 

However, I noticed there was still a delay where all the images were invisible while waiting for the whole page to load - guess it was because the function was fired on window.onload. Instead, I now set the margins and 'js-loaded' class on each img, and that will be done for each img.onload. That way each image will show as soon as it has loaded, independent on the others. The style is: 
`body #images img {visibility: hidden} 
body #images img.js-loaded {visibility: visible}`

Answer (score 1):

You could set all images to have a `visibility:hidden` (or alternatively `display:none`) style and then in your javascript remove that css property (or class) so that it appears after margin is applied